# Object volume on a specific virtual area using Intel Realsense and openCV

Tags: opencv, stereo-3d, lidar

I am doing a project which need to measure volume or H x W x T of an object (in ex: A box).I have some level of understanding in applying filters and finding contours in openCV and managed to calibrate and get depth of an image by using Intel RealSense camera.

[image]

[image]

So i have few questions in my mind.

1. How to find edges and coordinate of the box only within the virtually designated area? I have tried to perform canny & hough but i couldn't think of how to get only the lines of the box? Should i do apply masking or should i put a reference plane (say.. a plywood bigger than the object to be measured?)
2. Will viewing from this angle and distance will be successful? Should cv2 Affinity work in this method?

Please let me know if you need more questions.

Comment: They both same image ? I think no, because the depth and hd camera seems in different locations. You wanna get the edges in hd view or depth view ? What is the exact target you wanna reach ?

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk No they are not. I just put the picture to describe. HD view or depth view? Well this is where i am confused. My recent research based on the example provided with Intel RealSense SDK do have something that measures volume of rectangular via PCL. However this is my first experience handling PCL stuffs and i couldn't find how to view the points distance more user friend (like imshow) with a unit indicator.On the other hand i also need to differentiate which one is floor and which one is the box. My exact target is a finding x,y,z distance of a shape,say a box

Comment: You already install realsense libraries? If you dont install their sdk, u cant reach camera view via on software and you cant use it with opencv. Before all, your problem seems different. Not this one is the first problem u should focus on

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk I already installed their SDK.The depth map that you are seeing above is based on SDK

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk The SDK based on C/C++ and has Python wrapper. Above windows that you see is based on Python code